# I would like to be able to disable customers' accounts temporarily

Tags: customer, customer-account

Just disabling the login would be sufficient. I can't seem to find a plugin that does that and then allows the account to be reactivated. Would simply unconfirming the account do or would someone be able to just send a reactivation email to get around it?

Comment: Are you wanting to disable all accounts or specific ones?

Comment: @sean did you manage to find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this free module by Vinai: https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation

It allows you to active (or deactive) customers which blocks them from logging in